# Characteristic energy spectrum patterns in quantum chaos

Tags: quantum-mechanics, chaos-theory

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/quantum-chaos-subatomic-worlds/

In this article, the author says that "the energy levels of a chaotic quantum system exhibit strong correlations."

I can't find any reasons for it in this article, so I find some papers about quantum chaology but nothing can help me to solve the mystery.

Why chaotic quantum system's energy spectra are nearly correlated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy levels in chaotic quantum systems [often display](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/359522/75633) "level repulsion", by which it's meant that crossings or degeneracies are less likely to occur in chaotic systems than they do in regular ones.

If the levels are avoiding it each other, they can't be fully independent, which means they must display correlations.

Comment: @최희량 Good to know. BTW, if you'd like to have the SA article with figures, there is this [e-print](http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/451/resources/qm-chaos/scientificamerican0192-78.pdf) available.